# prove that polynomial has root of unity

Tags: polynomials, roots, roots-of-unity

Prove that $ f=x^n\pm x^m\pm1 $ is either irreducible over rationals or has a root which is a of unity. I tried to see what if $x=|r|e^{i\phi}$ but I have no proper result.

Comment: $x^2+1$ has both properties. So it's not "either or". Do you mean "root on the unit circle" or "root in $\{-1,1\}$?

Comment: maybe I made a error cuz english is not my native. I meant that it has 1st property or 2nd and I need to prove it

Comment: OK, a root on the complee unit circle.

Comment: x^n=1 and x complex

Comment: Also posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/134038/prove-that-polynomial-has-root-root-of-unityusing-reciprocal-polynomials without notification to either site about the post to the other.

Comment: Where does the problem come from?

Comment: This is a confusingly phrased question, since a polynomial does not "have a root of unity." Rather, it can have root which is a root of unity. It might seem pedantic, but the above is nonsensical.

Comment: yep! I meant has a root which is root of unity

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/56579/about-irreducible-trinomials seems relevant. Only considers $x^n - x^m - 1$. Maybe other cases are similar. Answered by @GerryMyerson there..

Comment: thanks a lot. that paper it refers to seems clear to understand

Comment: @Coco, amazing how much someone can forget in two years!