For what integers $m\gt n\gt 0$, the polynomial $x^m+x^n+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$?
I came up with this problem and have found it interesting.
Problem. For what integers $m\gt n\gt 0$, the polynomial $f(x)=x^m+x^n+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$?
If $mn\equiv 2 \pmod 3$, i.e. one of $m,n $ is congruent to $1 \bmod3$ and the other is $2 \bmod 3$, then $f(x)$ is divisible by $x^2+x+1$, hence reducible (unless $m=2$).
Moreover, let $d$ be the largest power of 3 to divide $m$ and $n$, $m_0=m/d$ and $n_0=n/d$, if $m_0n_0\equiv 2 \pmod 3$ and the condition "$\exists k,  m=2n=2\times 3^k$" fails, then $f(x)$ is reducible. 
But there are many other cases to consider, and I don't know what to do.
Thanks for any help in advance.

Irreducible over?

@Yathi $\mathbb Q$; fixed that issue

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3629623/irreducibility-of-a-family-of-polynomials, in particular, the reference in the answer to a book by Prasolov. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423599/prove-that-polynomial-has-root-of-unity and the link there to MathOverflow.

See also Ljunggren, On the irreducibility of certain trinomials and quadrinomials, Mathematica Scandinavica 8 (1960): 65-70. There is a link at https://eudml.org/doc/165734 and SELMER, ERNST S.. "On the irreducibility of certain trinomials." Mathematica Scandinavica 4 (1956): 287-302. http://eudml.org/doc/165635.might be more to the point. Finally, try https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56579/about-irreducible-trinomials

I will reproduce here my answer [copied from Math Reviews] to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56579/about-irreducible-trinomials (one should also see the other answer posted to that question, as well as a useful comment):
MR0124313 (23 #A1627)
Ljunggren, Wilhelm
On the irreducibility of certain trinomials and quadrinomials.
Math. Scand. 8 1960 65–70.
12.30
The author considers the irreducibility over the field of rational numbers of the polynomials $f(x)=x^n+ε_1x^m+ε_2x^p+ε_3$, where $ε_1,ε_2,ε_3$ take the values $\pm1$. He proves that if $f(x)$ has no zeros which are roots of unity, then $f(x)$ is irreducible; if $f(x)$ has exactly $q$ such zeros, then $f(x)$ can be factored into two factors with rational coefficients, one of which is of degree $q$ with all these roots of unity as zeros, while the other is irreducible (and possibly merely a constant). He also determines all possible cases where roots of unity can be zeros of $f(x)$. As a corollary he is able to give a complete treatment of the trinomial $g(x)=x^n+ε_1x^m+ε_2$, where $ε_1,ε_2$ take the values $\pm1$. The irreducibility of this trinomial was studied by E. S. Selmer, who gave a partial solution [Math. Scand. 4 (1956), 287--302; MR0085223 (19,7f); see also #A1628]. The methods used are direct and elementary.
Reviewed by H. W. Brinkmann
